# csquote: custom quote styles

Tags: quoting, csquotes, dialogue

I am typesetting a novel that features “Dialogue” by cats and other animals.

« *Cats speak like this* »

“People speak like this.”

I've had something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareQuoteStyle{english}%
    {\textquotedblleft}
    [\textquotedblleft]
    {\textquotedblright}
        [0.05em]
    {\textquoteleft}
    [\textquoteleft]
    {\textquoteright}


\DeclareQuoteStyle{cat}
    {\guillemotleft}{\guillemotright}
    {\guilsinglleft}{\guilsinglright}
\DeclareQuoteOption{cat}

\begin{document}
\foreignquote{cat}{Cats speak like this}
\end{document}
```

But this doesn't work. I think I need to declare `cat` as a language in `babel`? I can't quite figure out how this works from the `csquotes` documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use `\setquotesyle` or more conveniently define a `\catquote` command:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareQuoteStyle{english}%
    {\textquotedblleft}
    [\textquotedblleft]
    {\textquotedblright}
        [0.05em]
    {\textquoteleft}
    [\textquoteleft]
    {\textquoteright}

\DeclareQuoteStyle{cat}
    {\guillemotleft}{\guillemotright}
    {\guilsinglleft}{\guilsinglright}

\newcommand{\catquote}[1]{{\setquotestyle{cat}\enquote{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\setquotestyle{cat}
\enquote{Cats speak like this.}

\setquotestyle{english}
\enquote{People speak like this.}

\catquote{Cats speak like this.}

\enquote{People speak like this.}

\end{document}
```

Incidentally `\DeclareQuoteOption` is only usable in a configuration file and is meant to provide a package option.