# How to tell csquotes to italicize quotes in blockquote?

Tags: italic, csquotes

I am using `csquotes` for adding quotations in my thesis and I need to italicize (make cursive) both the in-text quotes (short quotes) and the paragraph quotes (long quotes separated into indented paragraph).

I have tried the solutions described here: [How to tell csquotes to italicize quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280619/how-to-tell-csquotes-to-italicize-quotes)

But with the first solution I couldn't figure how to get it to work without switching into French babel (which changes all my headers to French) and it wasn't italicizing the paragraph quotes.

The second solution worked for short quotes, but I didn't know how to adapt it to `\blockquotes` of the format: `\blockquote[citation]{quote}`, as it will italicize the citation instead of the quote.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For blockquotes, what you need is roughly this:

```
\patchcmd{\csq@bquote@i}{{#6}}{{\emph{#6}}}{}{}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\csq@bquote@i}{{#6}}{{\emph{#6}}}{}{}
\makeatother

%%% if you want italic quotation marks as well
%\DeclareQuoteStyle{american}[][]
%   {{\itshape\textquotedblleft}}[]{{\itshape\textquotedblright}}
%   [0sp]
%   {{\itshape\textquoteleft}}[]{{\itshape\textquoteright}}

\begin{document}

hello all

\blockquote[example]{some \enquote{text} here}

and goodbye

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For blockquotes, you can use the `\SetBlockEnvironment` command from the csquotes package. You first have to define an italic quote environment and then tell csquotes to use it for block quotations.

For inline quotes you can define your own quote style with `\DeclarQuoteStyle`. It takes optional arguments `outer init` and `inner init` where you can provide commands to be executed before starting the outer and inner quote, respectively.
Then use your custom style with `\setquotestyle`.

The following example is adapted from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/602305/168128) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227659/168128) answer:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% Make block quotes italic
\newenvironment{italicquote}{\quote\itshape}{\endquote}
\SetBlockEnvironment{italicquote}

% Make inline quotes italic, too
\DeclareQuoteStyle{italic}[\itshape][\itshape]
{\textquotedblleft}{\textquotedblright}
{\textquoteleft}{\textquoteright}
\setquotestyle{italic}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy lorem ipsum text

\begin{document}
    % Test inline quotes
    This is a test, what happens if I \enquote{enquote some text \enquote{and use an inner quote}}?
    
    \lipsum[1]

    % Test display block quotes
    \begin{displayquote}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{displayquote}
    \lipsum[3]

    % Test a block quote with citation
    \blockquote[citation]{This is a block quote. It is italicized, but the citation is not.}

\end{document}
```